# SBT: Evaluating sequence of tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to get the information about all modules in my sbt project.

Having the following code

```
lazy val getModule = taskKey[Module]("get single module info")
lazy val allModules = taskKey[Seq[Module]]("get all modules info")

getModule := Def.task {
  Module(name.value, description.value, version.value, organization.value)
}.value,

allModules := Def.task {
  val sbtModules = (ThisScope / thisProject).value.aggregate
  sbtModules.map { m =>
    (ThisScope.in(m) / getModule).value
  }
}.value
```

I'm getting the errors:

```
[error] problem: Task invocations inside anonymous functions are evaluated independently of whether the anonymous function is invoked or not.
...
[error] /Users/ikryvorotenko/projects/rae/rae-lib/project/SbtToGradlePlugin.scala:27:23: Illegal dynamic reference: m
[error]         (ThisScope.in(m) / getModule).value
```

Does sbt have anything to chain tasks dynamically?
Basically I'm looking for something like `Future.sequence` for chaining all tasks results into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few features described in [Tasks](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html) that might be helpful.

First, [Dynamic Computation with Def.taskDyn](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with) allows you to use the result of one task to compute the other. In your case, `allModules` should be `(Def.taskDyn { ... }).value`.

To aggregate a task across multiple subprojects etc, you can use [ScopeFilter](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#ScopeFilter) and `.all` method on a task key.