# evaluating a list of tasks inside of an sbt task

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to evaluate a list of tasks inside a single task.

this is my code:

```
val testPar: sbt.TaskKey[scala.Unit] = TaskKey("test-par")

testPar := {
  (Test / definedTests)
    .value
    .map(td => " " + td.name)
    .map(t => (Test / testOnly).toTask(t))
    .map(_.value)
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> error: Illegal dynamic reference: x$1
>        .map(_.value)

I tried using `Def.taskDyn` as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096741/245024 , but than I get this error:

> error: type mismatch;
>   found   : Seq[Unit]  required:
>   sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[?]]

I'm using sbt `1.3.9`
what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing a problem that I also fought quite often in the past.
In most cases a combination of taskDyn and recursion comes to the rescue:

```
val testPar: sbt.TaskKey[scala.Unit] = TaskKey("test-par")

testPar := Def.taskDyn {
  val tasks = (Test / definedTests).value
    .map(td => " " + td.name)
    .map(t => (Test / testOnly).toTask(t))

  flattenTasks(tasks)
}.value

def flattenTasks[A](tasks: Seq[Def.Initialize[Task[A]]]): Def.Initialize[Task[List[A]]] =
  tasks.toList match {
    case Nil => Def.task { Nil }
    case x :: xs => Def.taskDyn { flattenTasks(xs) map (x.value :: _) }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined tasPar's as TaskKey[Unit] and at then you are calling `toTask(t)` from testOnly:

```
val testPar: sbt.TaskKey[scala.Unit] = TaskKey("test-par")

testPar := {
  (Test / definedTests).value
    .map(td => " " + td.name)
    .map(t => (Test / testOnly).toTask(t))
}
```

and the type of `testOnly` is `sbt.InputKey[scala.Unit]`.
Where documentation says:

> The toTask method on Initialize[InputTask[T]] accepts the String input to apply and produces a task that can be used normally.

So, in your case `T` is `Unit` and you cannot chain further with `map` for input tasks

Comment: but if I manually specify all the test (ie: `(Test / testOnly).toTask("Test1").value; (Test / testOnly).toTask("Test2").value; ...`) it works correctly. so how can I make it work with a list?

Comment: `toTask` produces a task, so I must call the `.value` to make it run